# Getting Lot's Of error in mute command! (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is My Code! Error- message.guild.members.get is not a Function.

I am using Visual Studio Code but soon i will upload this seperate command file to repl.it

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: 'Mutes the Member',
    execute(message, args, Discord) {

        let tomute = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() ||
            message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
        if (!tomute) return
        message.reply('Error! Could not able to Find the Member!');
        if (tomute.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return
        message.reply("Error! You Can't Mute Them"); let muterole =
            message.guild.roles.find(muterole => muterole.name === "Muted");
        //start of create role   
        if (!muterole) {
            try {
                muterole = message.guild.createRole({
                    name: "Muted",
                    color: "#000000",
                    permissions: []
                })
                message.guild.channels.forEach(async (channel, id) => {
                    await channel.overwritePermissions(muterole, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                        ADD_REACTIONS: false
                    });
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
            }
        } if (!args[1]) {
            memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole.id);
            const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('ff0000')
                .setTitle('Muted!')
                .setDescription(`${member} has been Muted!`)
                .message.channel.send('newEmbed');
            return
        }
        memberTarget.roles.add(muteRole);
        const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('ff0000')
            .setTitle('Muted!')
            .setDescription(`${member} has been Muted!`)
            .message.channel.send('newEmbed');
        setTimeout(function () {
            memberTarget.roles.remove(muteRole);
        }, ms(args[1]));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is outdated (v11), you should update your code to v12

Update:

```
.get() => .cache.get();
.find() => .cache.find();
.createRole() => .roles.create();
.channels.forEach() => .channels.cache.forEach();
```

Official guide by discord.js to update v11 to v12, [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html)

Comment: Oh.. Thanks Bro!